# Add to Python Script from PowerShell Terminal?

Tags: python, powershell

I'm learning Python from "Learn Python the Hard Way" by Zed A. Shaw, and can't figure out:

1. I'm working in Powershell. How do I add a line of text to my python script (ex1.py) from the PowerShell terminal? I've tried (starting in PowerShell): `Add-Content ex1.py "print "Hello""` and other variations, but I get the message:

   > Add-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Hello'.
2. How do I run just one of the seven lines of text ex1.py currently has? Without doing some extra bash script? Again, I'm working from the Windows PowerShell terminal, so I don't think bash applies there.

Comment: FWIW, you'd be well-served to download your own text-editor like Notepad+ to write python in.

Comment: Is there particular lesson that requires doing this sort of thing? Any reason you can't just directly execute `python.exe` and use the REPL?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `Add-Content ex1.py 'print "Hello"'`
2. Use `python.exe -c "<cmd>"` to execute a single python command.